# How to stop FOUT (flash of unstyled text) upon load

Tags: html, css, preload, google-font-api

When I open my html, css and js files from my computer on either Chrome or IE (I haven't tried other browsers), I have the flash of unstyled text before my google font loads. I've combed through loads of posts on this exact topic and have tried many solutions, but I still cannot find a solution works.

At beginning of head tag in html file:

```
<style>html{visibility: hidden;opacity:0;}</style>
```

At end of css file:

```
html {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

This makes absolutely no difference for me.

Comment: You might be able to devise your own strategy based on [A modern font loading strategy with the vanilla JS FontFaceSet.load() method](https://gomakethings.com/a-modern-font-loading-strategy-with-the-vanilla-js-fontfaceset.load-method/).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the author of that article has presented a method of inducing the very behavior I'm trying to avoid - the flash of unstyled text.

Comment: Yup. However the article describes how it works and why. The strategy the author uses would be the same for what you're trying to do so the actual process just needs a little adjustment.

Comment: Using js for this is awkward. If I hide the body and then use js to show the body once the font is loaded, those who haven't enabled js won't see anything. If I use js to check if the font has loaded, and if not, hide the body, and if so, show the body, then I need to reference my js file at the beginning of my html file, which creates major front end functionality problems. I'm not sure how far I'd get trying to add js inline.

Comment: There's no simple fix for it. Either live with it or put in fancy BS to make it go away. As for disabled javascript, that's a choice the users' made. They know to expect issues with pages due to their choice and FOUT is a relatively minor issue.